# R: Customize Slope of Curve in Plot

Tags: r, graph

I want to graphically represent the slope of a line, where the line is determined by a formula taking the weighted average of a set of points. The weights are based on external factors not represented.

I have an aggregated graph with the x variable (price) on the x-axis and the dependent (quantity) on the y. I am trying to overlay that graph with another that is just a set of lines representing the steepness of the change in quantity over price we derived empirically tha is NOT equivalent to the slope of the curve.

The x axis should be price; the y should be volume; and the slopes of the curve should be the elasticity. Is there a way for me to do this in R?

Elasticity is change in quantity for $1 change in price. It's different at different price points.

```
df

Category       Price   Volume_Band     Elasticity 

alpha        $1      50,000          -0.5 
beta         $2      100,000         -1 
gamma        $3      200,000         -1.5 
delta        $4      250,000         -2
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the question? I read the stack overflow guidelines.

Comment: At least to me it's unclear what you want to do ("volume of demand"?, "elasticity"?). You don't give us data and an example of desired output. There is no code and you don't tell what you have tried or researched.

Comment: That was about the smallest possible improvement you could have made. I still have no idea what you're trying to do and you have provided no evidence that you've researched/tried anything, i.e. no code.

Comment: Does that mean you want some kind of spline interpolation where the slope at your data points is given? If that's the case, can you give more information what kind of functions should be used for the splines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure, how your graph should look like. I'll give two variants, but maybe you could provide a mock-up?

**Possibility 1:**

```
DF <- read.table(text="Category       Price   Volume_Band     Elasticity 
alpha        $1      50,000          -0.5
beta         $2      100,000         -1 
gamma        $3      200,000         -1.5 
delta        $4      250,000         -2",header=TRUE)

DF$Price <- as.numeric(gsub("\\$","",DF$Price))
DF$Volume_Band <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",DF$Volume_Band))

dx <- 0.2
dy <- dx*DF$Elasticity


DF$xstart <- DF$Price-dx
DF$xend <- DF$Price+dx
DF$ystart <- DF$Volume_Band-dy
DF$yend <- DF$Volume_Band+dy


library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x=Price, y=Volume_Band)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xstart,y=ystart,xend=xend,yend=yend))

print(p1)
```

[image]

Note that the slopes are too small to see.

**Possibility 2:**

```
p2 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x=Price, y=Volume_Band)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Elasticity),size=3) +
  scale_colour_gradient(high="black",low="red")

print(p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data it doesn't seem to imply much curvature so a straightline fit would produce:

```
 lm(dat[[4]]~dat[[3]])


Call:
lm(formula = dat[[4]] ~ dat[[3]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     dat[[3]]  
     -2e-01       -7e-06  

plot(dat[[3]],dat[[4]])
abline(coef(lm(dat[[4]]~dat[[3]])))
```